# Audio recording / UI and .apk building in Python for Android

Tags: android, python, audio-recording, audio-capture

I want to develop an android app that involves recording audio from the microphone. Unfortunately, I don't know java, so I've been looking into doing it in a python framework/platform. I need to be able to:

- build an 'elegant' UI (a simple one - buttons and lists);
- record and play audio;
- build an .apk file that I can publish on the Play Store.

I've looked into Kivy, but it seems audio capture is not available. Other solutions have that capability, but lack proper UI/apk building solutions.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I got an answer in the kivy users support google groups:
"Kivy can record audio on Android via the audiostream recipe 
(https://github.com/kivy/audiostream)".
I'll check it out as soon as possible.

Comment: bernardo.g your link has some unintentional trailing punctuation

Comment: Edit: The correct link is: https://github.com/kivy/audiostream